# What is wrong with my validator function?

Tags: php

I was solving a challenge algorithm and  I was told to create a password validator that would check if:

- Password length was not less than 6 and it is not greater than 20.
- it must have atleast a character from [A-Z]
- it must have atleast a character from [a-z]
- it must have aleast a numerical character [0-9]

I wrote this function to validate it:

```
<?php
function Validate($input){
    $length = strlen($input);

    if($length < 6 || $length > 20){
        return 'False';
    }
    if( !preg_match('/[0-9]+/', $input) ){
        return 'False';
    }

    if( !preg_match('/[A-Z]+/', $input) ){
        return 'False';
    }

    if( !preg_match('/[a-z]+/', $input) ){
        return 'False';
    }

    return 'True';
}
?>
```

The challenge reported that my function failed two (2) test case out of four(4). Please could anyone help me with any possible test case that would point out what is missing in my function?

Comment: Why are you returning string instead of `true` and `false`? Remove the quotation marks from the `return 'False'` and `return 'True'` statents and try it again.

Comment: @kalehmann That is what the challenge wants me to return

Comment: @StanleyAloh then abort the challenge -returning bools as strings ... such hysteria!

Comment: @kalehmann The challenge require I return a string. I got two cases right already

Comment: As an aside, that's a fairly awful password validator; I tend to use randomly generated passwords that are longer than 20 characters (stored in a password locker)...

Comment: If the challenge doesn't tell you which test cases you're failing, or what data set it's using, then I'm not sure how much we can help. Your code *looks* fine for the requirements, but we'd only be guessing as to why it might fail the cases.

Comment: as iainn already mentioned - you've to provide the failed cases

Answer (score 5):

As the comments have already noted, you are returning strings, not boolean values, from your function.  But, you don't need such bloated logic to check the password requirements.  I would recommend using `preg_match` here with a single regular expression:

```
function Validate($input) {
    return preg_match("/(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9]).{6,20}/", $input));
}
```

### Demo

By the way, [the logic in your current function is working](http://rextester.com/MMAEHJ13532), and I don't see why the code test should be having issues with it.  Maybe your return types should *not* be strings.

Comment: but this doesn't cater for character length validation --> if($length < 6 || $length > 20)

Comment: @parpar `{6,20}`

Comment: @parpar Check the demo link to convince yourself that the regex is correct.

Comment: tried it using the demo. still valid when you enter more than 20 characters

Comment: What does this do that the code in the original question doesn't? That is, how does this actually provide an answer?

Comment: I tried it but the challenge program still say that two test cases are wrong. I feel the fault is with the program

Comment: @StanleyAloh That's my feeling as well.  It your code (or my code) is really failing for both booleans and strings, then maybe the program has a bug.  For this reason, I truly loathe technical interviews which use sites like HackerRank.

Comment: Oh yeah, the RegExp is missing start/end boundaries (`^ ... $`) to fix the length.

Answer (score 0):

This `Validate` function returns a true value regardless of the input - thus any test with valid password will succeed and any test with invalid password will fail.

Details on what is considered true and false in PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

Comment: I have tried the suggestion. It gave me false all through. The program stated that I should return a string.